# If $X$ poisson and $X=X_1+X_2$, then integer valued $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also poisson.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, poisson-distribution

I know if $X$ and $Y$ are poisson, then $X + Y$ is also poisson. But now I met a strange problem which states that if $X$ is poisson, $X_1 + X_2 = X$ and $X_1$,$X_2$ are independent nonnegative integer valued then both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are also poisson.
I try to use the characteristic function to solve this problem but didn't get any helpful result.

Comment: Is there an additional hypothesis like independence or similar?

Comment: @Ian Yes, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent

Comment: @user147893, Are $X_1$ and $X_2$ identically distributed?

Comment: @ki3i no, there is no any other condition than they are nonnegative integer valued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Raikov's theorem. A proof can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/%5BEugene_Lukacs%5DRaikov.pdf) (Theorem 8.2.2).

Comment: I will check it!

Comment: The link is now 404...can you give a new one?